# HttpUrlConnection Timeout issue works with local host but while using remote IP its not working

Tags: java, spring, networking

```
String dbUrl=ccdList.get(0).getCcdCustSysURL();
    int port =ccdList.get(0).getCcdCustSysPortNo();
    String Url = dbUrl+":"+port;                   
    String SOAPAction = "";
    
// Create the connection where we're going to send the file.
        URL url = new URL(Url);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(0);
        httpConn.setReadTimeout(0);
        ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes());
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

with this code, I can not able to access the remote server application using IP. but it works fine on my localhost. But why?

Comment: Also, I checked there is no proxy. exact java issue - java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect Also I tried with increase timeout seconds nothing works.

Comment: Can you ping the remote host? Do you have some evidence that it is running?

Comment: @user207421 I am new to java. I just created a new project with eclipse and it works fine with my localhost third-party application. similarly, I tried with my remote Ip and remort port.

Comment: Yes, the remote application is in a running state.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error
21.81 s
6.73 KB

Comment: Can you provide the exception stack trace? And have you tried to change the URL for something real (google.com) for example? What exactly do you expect to receive?

Answer (score 0):

it working if using the local loopback address and LAN IP (127.0.0.1)?If it is available, you need to check your firewall policy.the best way is to telnet your remote IP and Port make sure it connectable.